# About the proof of the Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm self-studying from the book [Understanding Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950605) by Stephen Abbott, and I have a question about the prove of theorem 3.3.4 on page 84 (i.e. the Heine-Borel theorem).

To be more specific, let us assume $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to be compact.$^1$ Then we would like to prove that this implies that $K$ is closed.$^2$ Stephen Abbott proceeds by considering a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x = \lim x_n$, where $(x_n)$ is contained in $K$. By definition of a compact set, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, and it follows from a well-known theorem$^3$ that $(x_{n_k})$ converges to the same limit $x$. Finally, the definition of a compact set requires that $x \in K$. Then according to Stephen Abbott, this proves that $K$ is closed.

But in his prove he has assumed that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges. What happens if $(x_n)$ does not converge?  Then we can still have a subsequence that converges to a limit, right? If so, then I think his theorem is incomplete, or am I missing something?

---

$^1$ A set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is *compact* if every sequence in $K$ has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in $K$.

$^2$ A set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is *closed* if it contains its limit points.$^{2.1}$

$^{2.1}$ A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $K$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_\epsilon (x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $K$ in some point other than $x$.

$^3$ Subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence.

Comment: Just a note about terminology, technically your $^1$ is called sequentially compact. In general topological spaces this doesn't necessarily imply compact nor compact imply this.

Comment: If u ve a sequence that does not converge then u dont have to show anything.

Comment: @YonedaLemma could you please elaborate on that? Because that is exactly what I am confused about.

Comment: @YonedaLemma For the proof, his first assumption is that he is considers a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x= \lim x_n$. But what if we consider a sequence $(x'_n)$ that does not converge. As far as I know, we can still have a convergent subsequence $(x'_{n_k})$, but now we cannot use the theorem that "subsequences of a *convergent* sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence", and so his prove breaks down. I must be missing something, but I don't see what it is.

Comment: $K$ is closed iff every convergent seq. in $K$ converges against a point in $K$. So u have to show: **If** $(x_n)$ is in $K$ and conv. against some $x$ **then** $x$ is in $K$. How: If $(x_n)$ is a seq. in $K$ that converges then because $K$ is compact, $(x_n)$ has a convergent subseq. with limit in $K$. By the theorem u mentioned the limit of the subsequent is identical to the limit of the original $(x_n)$ - so it must be in $K$ $\diamond$. (If for a proof u start with a seq. that does not conv. then u are just not about to prove that $K$ suffices the given definition of being a closed set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition** (Hausdorff space)

A topological space $X$ is called **Hausdorff** or $T_2$ space if and only iff every two points $x,y\in X$ have disjunct neighbourhoods $x\in O_x\subset x$ and $y\in O_y\subset X$.

**Example** (Metric spaces are Hausdorff)

Every **metric space** $M$ is (as a topological space) $T_2$ - for each $x, y\in M$ say $d:=d(x,y)$ is their distance, then the $\epsilon$-spheres around $x$ and $y$ with $\epsilon < \frac{d}{2}$ (f.i. open intervals with midpoint $x$ resp. $y$) are disjoint neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$. Therefore especially $R$ is $T_2$ (since $R$ is a metric space).

**Proposition** (Compact subsets of $T_2$ spaces are closed)

Say $A\subset X$ where $X$ is a topological space that is *Hausdorff* (f.i. $R$).

If $A$ is *compact* then $A$ is *closed*.

*Proof*: Say $X$ is $T_2$ and $A\subset X$ is compact. We show that $A^c$ is open (and thereby $A$ is closed) by showing that any $y\in A^c$ has a neighbourhood $V_y\subset A^c$:

Say $y\in A^c$ arbitrary. Then for any $x\in A$ we have a neighbourhood $O_x$ of $x$ and a neighbourhood $V_y^x$ of $y$ that is disjoint to $O_x$ (since $X$ is $T_2$). So we have
$$A\subset \bigcup_{x\in A}O_x$$ and
$$\bigcup_{x\in A}O_x \cap\bigcap_{x\in A}V_y^x=\emptyset$$

and therefore
$$\bigcap_{x\in A}V_y^x\subset A^c$$

Because $A$ is compact we can argue with finitely many $x\in A$. But then $V_y:=\bigcap_{x\in A}V_y^x$ is open - so altogether $V_y$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ that is contained in $A^c$. $\diamond$

---

(For $X=R$ the $O_x$ and $V_y^x$ become open intervals in $R$ with midpoint $x$ resp. $y$. )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is too advanced for the book I'm currently reading. The author has not defined what a topological space or a metric space is. (But don't delete the answer, because it might be useful for someone else.)

Comment: Yes I see - you are just confused about some simple point namely what to show for the proof. When besides the things the author shows u want also to show something else (f.i. for non converging sequences in $K$) then u are trying to do too much - see above comment.

Comment: I think I understand it with your help. In order to prove that $K$ is closed, we must show that $K$ contains its limit points. A well-known theorem$^1$ tells us that every limit point $x$ of $K$ corresponds to some convergent sequence $(x_n)$ contained in $K$, that is, $x = \lim x_n$. Then he subsequently uses that to prove that $K$ is closed if $K$ is compact, as I have described above.
---
$^1$ Theorem: A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $K$ if, and only if, $x = \lim x_n$ for some sequence $(x_n)$ contained in $K$ satisfying $x_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you double check if the above is correct?

Comment: Not quite - a limit point of a set is a point that some sequence in that set converges to (usually that is taken as definition - not as well known theorem). A limit point of a set therefore corresponds not to a sequence in that set that converges to it but in general to any sequence in the set that converges to it.

Comment: The point is: to prove the proposition "*if* **a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ converges to a point $x$** *then* $x\in K$" you should do the following: regard an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$ **converging against some $x$** (not necessarily in $K$) and then: show that $x$ must be in $K$.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting, the author of my book has defined a limit point as: A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $K$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_\epsilon (x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $K$ in some point other than $x$. In other words, the element $x \in X$ is a limit point of $K$ if every neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ contains a point of $K$ other than $x$.

Comment: yes thats equivalent: if any $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $K$ tehn there is a sequence in $K$ that converges against $x$ (choose one point out of every $\epsilon$-neighbourhood - these points get necessarily arbitrary near to $x$). If on other hand some sequence converges in $K$ against $x$ (not necessarily in $K$), then by definition of *convergence* (allmost all - but thats not the point here) parts of the sequence are in any neighbourhood of $x$ - since the sequence is in $K$ this means any neighbourhood of $x$ intersects with $K$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I get it now! (I have accepted your answer based on the comments, because I'm not in a position to judge/check/understand the original answer you have given me.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are not understanding what is going on. You need to prove that $K$ is closed, so you must prove that any point $x$ that is the limit of a sequence of pints $x_n \in K$ belongs to $K$. So you *must* assume that $x=\lim_n x_n$!

Comment: Yeah, I am still confused because that is not the definition of a closed set, as far as I understand it. Is there a theorem that every sequence in a closed set must be convergent?

Comment: Such a theorem would be false... The author is using this definition of closedness: a set $C$ (in a metric space) is closed if $x \in C$ whenever $x=\lim_n x_n$ with $x_n \in C$ for every $n$. In other words, $C$ contains its cluster points.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm still confused. For the proof, his first assumption is that he is considers a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x= \lim x_n$. But what if we consider a sequence $(x'_n)$ that does not converge. As far as I know, we can still have a convergent subsequence $(x'_{n_k})$, but now we cannot use the theorem that "subsequences of a *convergent* sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence", and so his prove breaks down. I must be missing something, but I don't see what it is.

Comment: I think I understand it, but I'm not sure. In order to prove that $K$ is closed, we must show that $K$ contains its limit points. A well-known theorem$^1$ tells us that every limit point $x$ of $K$ corresponds to some convergent sequence $(x_n)$ contained in $K$, that is, $x = \lim x_n$. Then he subsequently uses that to prove that $K$ is closed if $K$ is compact, as I have described above.
---
$^1$ Theorem: A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $K$ if, and only if, $x = \lim x_n$ for some sequence $(x_n)$ contained in $K$ satisfying $x_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, your last interpretation is fine.